# facebook like button for uploaded images

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have uploaded one image on facebook and i would like a "like button" for that specific image.

Is this possible? I would like to have that button on an external site and give the opportunity to people to like the image.i know it can be done using the graph api but i would prefer the button solution.

thank you

Comment: what do you mean by button solution and what kind of button you are talking about?

Comment: i mean the standard facebook like button: <div class="fb-like" ...>

Comment: as far as I know you can attach a fb like button to a particular webpage. of your site...I don't think so you can associate a fb like button to only a particular image you uploaded

Comment: i just hoped there was a right value for the data-href attribute that points to an uploaded image